# How to make a makefile properly, Why is this makefile not correct

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I am trying to understand how to make a make file in Linux, and some one suggested to me to use this:

```
target: mytalkc.c mytalkd.c
    gcc mytalkc.c -o mytalkc
    gcc mytalkd.c -o mytalkd
```

When executing the above code exactly using "make" in the terminal everything ran great and everything compiled and made a executable successfully. So I thought this was correct, and I went with this for my makefile.

After futher documentation I learned that the correct way to make a makefile was not what I had above....

My question is, why does "target:" work and why was make was able to complete everything with no errors. Also why is things like "all:" used in make files over "target:" ?

Thanks in advance and sorry if it seems obvious, but I am new to Linux programming.

Comment: This question is very open-ended, and I don't think one answer will cover everything.  I recommend try looking at existing open-source makefiles.  They often include multiple targets.  'All' would build them all.  'Clean' gets rid of temporary files and derivatives resetting everything.  'Install' will often set everything up for use.  Also see 'man make'.

Comment: Really all I want to know is why the heck does "Target:" work in a make file, I assume that it allows you to specify the source code files you want to target in the current directory, but people have told me this is the wrong way to make a make file.

Comment: Think of the Makefile as an abstraction.  Compiling/linking on your system targeting your system may work fine with a command-line gcc call, but it will not work for all systems.  Others may have different tool chains, libraries, configurations, or will target another platform.  A properly designed Makefile will take care of all this.

Comment: Did you take time to **read** (or begin reading) **the [documentation of GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html)** ??? You really should, it is well written, with a good tutorial part!

Comment: Please don't edit away your questions! I've restored your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically a makefile is structured into multiple target rules, which contain dependencies that may rely on other dependences and so on. The word "all" is suggestive of "all targets", which means any dependencies of the "all" target are built. Additionally, some implementations of make allow for phony targets, such as "all", that tell make not to look for a file with one of the suffixes in a predefined suffix list, such as "all.c" to build the binary (program) with the filename "all".

Your actual question regarding why "target" works pertains to the behavior of make. It automatically makes the first target in the makefile unless a specific target is given. In your case, "target" is the first target in your file, so "make" by itself will make it (often "all" is used instead, but it is just a name; you should use "all" to simply because it is common practice).

Here is an example of how your file might be reworked with multiple targets (see the documentation for your make utility to understand the syntax, such as "info make" or "man make"):

```
all: mytalkc mytalkd

mytalkc: mytalkc.c
    gcc $< -o $@

mytalkd: mytalkd.c
    gcc $< -o $@
```

There are a lot of other things to address outside the scope of this answer, including implicit suffix rules and compiling several individual parts of a program/library together to create the program (splitting makefile rules into `program/library: object1.o object2.o main.o` and then individual rules for e.g. `object1.o: object1.c`). However, those are the basics that you need to know for now.

Comment: Yes, you could name it "myprogram" or "this_is_sparta" or "hal9000", and it would work as long as it was the first rule in the makefile. In my example code, if you moved the rule for mytalkc to be first, it would only make that rule, meaning "mytalkd" would not get built. You can also use "make <target>" to build a specific target instead of the first one in the file, such as "make all", "make mytalkc", etc. That way, if "all" isn't first, you can still "make all" to build everything.

Answer (score 0):

For what i know if you compile using gcc mytalkc.c -o mytalkc you are just compiling the source file as an object, it means that the compilation went well, but the file is not executable still because you haven't done any liking.

Try with this:

```
all: mytalkc.o mytalkd.o

mytalkc.o: mytalkc.c
gcc mytalkc.c -c mytalkc.c

mytalkd.o: mytalkd.d
gcc mytalkc.c -c mytalkd.c
```

invoking make all

Comment: Thank you for the input. However, the line gcc mytalkc.c -o mytalkc creates the executable and does the linking for the object. and the executable runs perfectly. Everything in the make file makes everything and it all runs great, but I still don't understand why "target:" works or why it is successful. I assume from what I read, "target:" specifically allows you to define the source code you need, but I have a lot of people tell me it is not the correct way to make a make file, but it works fine.

Comment: I got what you mean. Basically, for what i know of course, when you call 'make all' make open the makefile and looks at the line all. In this line it finds all: mytalkc.o mytalkd.o, so it recursively checks for mytalkd.o and mytalkc.o. At those line it find something like [outputfile]:[inputfile] and below that the instruction to execute in order to compile it. In your case, when you call make target it does two compilation at once, because below the like target: mytalkc mytalkd finds both the instruction to compile the two source file.